# Cannot retrieve all nodes from XML

Tags: php, xml

I cannot figure out how to retrieve all nodes in a simple XML file using PHP.

Here is the test.xml :

```
<Table>
<Row attr1="kkn" attr2="ede" attr3="dfdf"></Row>
<Row attr1="nknkn" attr2="kkp" attr3="lk"></Row>
<Row attr1="huhtg" attr2="lmml" attr3="kpk"></Row>
<Row attr1="lklk" attr2="esr" attr3="lkde"></Row>
</Table>
```

and here is my php code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('/path/to/folder/test.xml');
foreach ($xml->Row as $row) {
         dd($row);
}
```

When running the script, I am only getting the first Row entry. How can I loop to get all nodes ?

thanks

Comment: I get 4 results. https://3v4l.org/9C235 What else is in the loop?

Comment: You wouldn't have asked this question, if you had really known what `dd()` does! Just a quick Google search got my answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

use `print_r($row)`

dd means "dump and die" so after the first loop it dies and does not move to the second

Comment: Same with me!!! Didn't know what `dd()` does and now I understood. It was just a Google search away!

Comment: Could i get some explanation at least on why i got downvoted since this is the answer to OP's question?

Comment: Probably because the answer was too easy. Never understood why people down vote for that though. It does answer the question. It'd make more sense to downvote the question. The dup doesn't really address the issue in this instance.